# jQuery Autocomplete Combobox add new Item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I currently want to create the following solution with "jQuery UI Autocomplete - Combobox":
I load entries from a database, which can be selected. If a value does not exist, the user should be offered to add its value.

My basis is currently: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Now I have adapted to "_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) ... "

I removed the part "// Remove invalid value" and replaced it with the following line:

```
$('#name1').append('<option value='+ value + ' selected>'+ value + '</option>');
```

This works from the principle also. Only the value "#name1" is still a fixed value and I currently fail to get this name somehow. With "this.input.name" and similar calls it does not work. The search does not lead me to the solution.

What chances do I have to modify the part "// Remove invalid value" for my purposes?

Many thanks in advance. SPagesDE

```
_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
        
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
            return;
        }
        
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
            if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
            return;
        }
        
        
        
        $('#name1').append('<option value='+ value + ' selected>'+ value + '</option>');
        
        
        
    },
```

Comment: If you review the example, you can see that the original element, `this.element` is hidden and that `this.input` is created, see line 45. This new input does not have a ID attribute. Suggest using `this.element.find("select")` as the target.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. It helped me a lot.

The solution to the problem:

```
$('#'+this.element.attr("id")).append('<option value='+ value + ' selected>'+ value + '</option>');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).